# architecture of loaded framework

Tags: macos, architecture, frameworks, 32bit-64bit

My application is linked with one system framework. The framework architecture is  32/64 bit standard Universal. The architecture of my application is also the same.

  1.First I run My application in 64 bit architecture so it will load the framework with 64 bit architecture.
  2.Next I run the  My application in 32 bit architecture .

**Question:** When I run my application in 32 bit mode whether it will load the framework with 32 bit or it will call the methods of already loaded 64 bit framework.How framework(dynamic library) will be loaded is it based on loading process architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32 bit apps needs 32 bit parts of the framework used, and 64 bit apps needs 64 bit parts of the framework used. There is no automatic translation involved.